# Simple GET request with PHP cURL to send SMS text message

Tags: php, curl, sms, http-get

I'm creating quick web app that needs to send a php-created message from within php code.  cURL is apparently the tool for the job, but I'm having difficulty understanding it enough to get it working.

The documentation for the API I'm dealing with is [here](http://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/SMS_Notify!).  In particular I want to use the simple GET-based sms notification documented [here](http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/help/operations/SimpleSMSsend).  The latter resource states that the GET API is simply:

```
http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/SimpleSMSsend?PhoneNumber={PHONENUMBER}&Message={MESSAGE}&LicenseKey={LICENSEKEY}
```

And indeed, if I type the following URL into a browser, I get the expected results:

```
http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/SimpleSMSsend?PhoneNumber=15362364325&Message=mymessage&LicenseKey=2134234882347139482314987123487
```

I am now trying to create the same affect within php.  Here is my attempt:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$num = '13634859126';
$message = 'some swanky test message';

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/SimpleSMSsend?PhoneNumber=".urlencode($num)."&Message=".urlencode($message)."&LicenseKey=2345987342583745349872");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My other PHP webpages work fine, so I know php and apache are all set up correctly.  But When I point my browser at the above page, I get no message on my phone.  Can anybody show me what I'm doing wrong?

*Note: all numbers are faked... as you might have suspected.*

Comment: Are you running your server locally? You might not be allowing Apache the chance to dial out to the wider internet.

Comment: Have you tried plugging that URI in a web browser to see if it works that way first?

Comment: Berryman :what is the response you have received ?

Comment: Nothing appeared on the screen.  If you check below (PurplePilot), I added a print output statement and nothing was sent to the screen.  I also commented out the "return transfer" line mentioned in that email and nothing was returned.  In all things, assume ignorance on my part.

Comment: Berryman - do you need to view page source in order to check the XML response?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you really need CURL? You simply use PHP's `file_get_contents($url)`, which will do a GET request and will return response value.

Comment: Chosen as answer because it worked and it was easy... so thanks!  Although it was slow.  I imagine that there's still some smarter way to do this that doesn't involve halting until the SMS message is sent.  Does it involve full-fledged ajax?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no return output, probably the cURL fails.
Check the error code of the returned resource to determine the cause of the error.

```
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$curlerrno = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $curlerrno;
```

The error code list: [libcurl-errors](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I advise to use cURL timeout settings too:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are forming the URL correctly and as one comment says check it manually in a browser I am not sure where your data is going  when it comes back so try

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // tell the return not to go to the browser

     $output = curl_exec($ch); // point the data to a variable

     print "<br />"; // output the variable
     print $output;
     print "<br />";
```

Other things to try are

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "93.221.161.69"); // telling the remote system where to send the data back
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); // pretend you are IE/Mozilla in case the remote server expects it
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // setting as a post
```

Comment: Thats probably the next step, but as he doesn't get a text message, the GET is probably not even performed, so no data to come back.

Comment: No output to screen, no message on my phone.  Is it possible that something is wrong with my code above?  I really don't understand PHP enough at this point to know what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it
PhoneNumber=$num

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/SimpleSMSsend?PhoneNumber=".urlencode($num)."&Message=".urlencode($message)."&LicenseKey=2345987342583745349872");